# Complement of triangle-free graphs

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Is it true that if the complement $\overline{G}$ of a triangle-free graph is connected then ${G}$ is $P_5$-free? - $P_5$ is a path on 5 vertices.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose not, i.e., $\overline{G}$ contains $P_5$, with vertices $v_1, \dots, v_5$ in that order. Then $v_1v_3v_5$ forms a triangle in $G$, a contradiction.